# What does the "!" sign do in python? Or is it a Linux commad?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm following a Python Notebook on the google cloud tutorials and I meet some commands that I can't understand that start with "!", such as:

```
!find {EXPORT_PATH}
```

or

```
!saved_model_cli show --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default --dir {EXPORT_PATH}
```

what does that mean? Is it even python or maybe it's some Linux console stuff? I don't know, please help me!!!

Comment: This is not python, it's a common addition in python shells (and notebooks) that means: run everything after the exclamation mark as a shell command (which is probably bash).

Comment: Thank you very much smassey